# Trying to understand loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, for-loop

New to Powershell scripting from Python. I'm just not sure why '$i += 1' isn't overwriting $i prior to the first 'write-host("i: ")' :

```
$myList = 5.6, 4.5, 3.3, 13.2, 4.0, 34.33, 34.0, 45.45, 99.993, 11123

write-host("using for loop")
for ($i = 0; $i -le ($myList.length - 1); $i += 1){
    write-host("i: ")
    $i
    write-host("myList[i]: ")
    $myList[$i]
}
```

I don't understand what the semicolons are doing and how it relates to the code block below. The code works as I want it to. But I read it as "initialize i to equal 0, if i is less than or equal to 9- increment i by 1". But if that was the case then i would be set to 1 before the first time write-host is executed. Instead it passes 0 and then increments $i.

Comment: You are telling $i to start at 0 (first loop) and increment 1 at the end of each loop while $i is less than or equal to list length minus 1. If you want to start at 1, set $i to 1 in the beginning.

Comment: also ... [1] you should NOT use `()` around input to a cmdlet or function unless you KNOW it is needed. your `Write-Host` calls don't seem to need it. [2] you left off the `$` in your `W-H` calls so the variable is not evaluated ... it just prints `i: ` & `myList[i]: `. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

The translation is

`set $variable equal to 0` ;
`do a thing while $variable is less than OR equal to (<number of items in list> -1)` ;`finally set $variable equal to $variable + 1`

```
for (<Initial iterator value>; <Condition>; <Code to increase iterator>)
{
    <Statement list>
}
```

*The `Statement list` executes **before** the `Code to increase iterator`*

#### STEP 1

At the beginning of the for loop statement, the Initial value is read and stored into the memory.

Example: `$i = 0`

#### STEP 2

The for loop statement evaluates the boolean result of the expression inside the Condition placeholder. If the result is $false, the for loop is terminated. If the result is $true, then the for loop continues to the next step.

Example: `$i -le ($list.length -1)`

#### STEP 3

PowerShell runs the code inside the Statement list placeholder. There could be one or more commands, script blocks, or functions.

Example: `Write-Ouput $i`

#### STEP 4

In this step, the expression in the Repeat placeholder is run, which will update the current value of the Initial placeholder. Then, the flow will go back to Step 2.

Example: `$i++`